# Let $Q=[0,1]\times[0,2]$. Find the rotation matrix $(A)$for the angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$ upon this set. Is $A(Q)$ measurable and a elementary set?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $Q=[0,1]\times[0,2]$. Find the rotation matrix  $(A)$for the angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$ upon this set. Is $A(Q)$ measurable and a elementary set?

First off, I know that $A$ is a linear map, and a linear map of any measurable set is, in fact measurable. With the question of :Is it an elementary set? I can intuitively say it isn't, because the map should be a slanted rectangle in respect to the $xy$ plane so the boundary of that, cannot be covered by a finite number of intervals from $\mathbb{R^2}$. Basically the same reason a triangle isn't a elementary set.

My problem is finding this matrix. How is this done at all? Also, I would like to know if I were asked to find the translation matrix $(B)$ upon this set, the translation being defined with a vector say $(a,b)$.

Comment: The (counterclockwise) rotation matrix by angle $\theta$ is given by
$$
\pmatrix{\cos \theta & - \sin \theta\\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta}
$$
There is no matrix that simply takes in a vector $v$ and produces a translated vector $Bv$; you would need to use homogeneous coordinates for something like that.

Comment: How do you mean homogeneous coordinates? Example?

Comment: You're welcome.  [See this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations).